# Kotlin Coroutine ViewModel UnitTesting does not cover viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am facing issues in passing Coroutine UnitTestcase for  ViewModel  . I am using MVVM retrofit .
Though I mocked the result , its displaying result as "null" 
Please find below UnitTest case class:

```
val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
@Test
fun `check viewmodel fetches data correctly`() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest{
    var retroRxModel = RetroRxModel("tile", "body", "1")
    var retroRXModelList = ArrayList<RetroRxModel>()
    retroRXModelList.add(retroRxModel)
    response = Response.success(retroRXModelList)
    retroCoroutineViewModel = RetroCoroutineViewModel(testDispatcher)
    if (retrofit != null) {

        if (apiService != null) {
            Mockito.`when`(apiService.fetchUserPosts()).thenReturn(response)
        }
    }
    retroCoroutineViewModel.fetchResponseFromAPI()
    println("Loading Val::::${retroCoroutineViewModel.fetchLoadStatus()?.value}")
    println("PostLive Dat::::${retroCoroutineViewModel.fetchPostLiveData().value}")
    Assert.assertEquals(true,retroCoroutineViewModel.loading?.value)



}
```

Please find viewmodel method to be tested:

```
fun fetchResponseFromAPI(){
    viewModelScope.launch (dispatcher){
       // postsMutableLiveData.postValue(null)
        try{

            val response  = apiService.fetchUserPosts()
            if(response.isSuccessful){
                postsMutableLiveData.postValue(response.body())
                loading.postValue(false)
               // loading.value = false
            }else{
                loading.postValue(false)
                errorOnAPI.postValue("Something went wrong::${response.message()}")
            }



        }catch (e:Exception){
            loading.postValue(false)
            errorOnAPI.postValue("Something went wrong::${e.localizedMessage}")
        }

    }

}
```

**ViewModelFactory:**

```
class RetroCoroutineViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(RetroCoroutineViewModel::class.java)) {
        return RetroCoroutineViewModel(Dispatchers.Main) as T
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
}


}
```

When tried to run unittest , I see the control is returned  after executing the below line in ViewModel without running through other code though data is mocked:
 val response  = apiService.fetchUserPosts()

Please help me in resolving this issue . 
 I am using mockito framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `retroCoroutineViewModel` is not using the mocked `apiService` instance.

The object of `viewmodel` is being created and the `apiService` is being mocked (considering the ifs are being executed) but the `apiService` object in `retroCoroutineViewModel` object is different than the mocked instance so you need to make sure that the `retroCoroutineViewModel` object has the mocked `apiService` object of your service (pass `apiService` via constructor to RetroCoroutineViewModel?)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed my issue. I passed  apiService from ViewModelFactory  to Viewmodel. Since its mocked in Test class, I passed that mocked value. Hence my test case passed now. Thanks  for your help.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, Happy Coding!